# When I click on the demonstrate block regions, I get an access denied message

Tags: theming, blocks

I logged-in as an admin. And when I click on the demonstrate block regions, I get an access denied message in Drupal-7.

I have cleared all caches. But, still get the same problem. 
Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Did you check your permissions settings?

Comment: File permission is 755.

Comment: This could happen if your theme is set to default but not enabled. Go to admin/appearance and make sure the theme is enabled.

Comment: Thank you so much Pontus Nilsson.. 
It works.. My admin theme was enabled different than my custom theme.. 
Now, I have enabled my theme thru admin/appearance .. And it works perfect.. 
Thanks a lot!!